# How to get rowvalue of selected combobox in Qtableview?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have Qtableviews, I have added combobox in table2 and values in combobox getting from table1 col0, so when user select item in combo2, I need to get the row value of selected item?

1. How can I do using indexwidget?
2. After getting row value then I can compare the combobox text and perform the calculation.
   As what I shared is working but when user select same value in 2 rows (diff) combobox then its not working (not getting data in 2 time).

```
void Gear_model::calR2() {
QAbstractItemModel* table1 = ui.tableView->model();
QAbstractItemModel* table2 = ui.tableView_2->model();
QComboBox* combo2;
QString col2;
for (int irowsl = 0, maxI = table2->rowCount(); irowsl < maxI; ++irowsl)
{
    const QModelIndex idx1 = table2->index(irowsl, 2);
    combo2 = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(ui.tableView_2->indexWidget(idx1)); 
    col2 = combo2->currentText();
    for (int irowsM = 0, maxI = table2->rowCount(); irowsM < maxI; ++irowsM) {
        qDebug() << "combo2 =" << col2;                                        
        if (col2 == table1->data(table1->index(irowsM, 0)).toString()) {
            double pitchradius2 = table1->data(table1->index(irowsM, 6)).toDouble();
            table2->setData(table2->index(irowsl, 10), radius2);
            qDebug() << "R2 =" << col2 << radius2;
        }
    }
 }
```

Cannot figure out how to get the selected value of the combobox for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
after combo2
I added

```
if (combo2!=NULL) {
//my previous code
}
```